# Add entry to a table for each distinct entry in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of items

[image]

I want to add a new row for each distinct customerid that adds a new role called say z
so for instance the above would then become:

[image]

I could do this manually but there are over 750K lines in this table so that would take awhile

I will also hardcode the entries for date and user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert` with a query to generate one row per distinct `customerid`:

```
insert into items (created, createdby, customerid, role)
    select getdate(), 1, customerid, 'z'
    from items i
    group by customerid;
```

I'm not sure what you want for `createdby`, so I just set it to `1`.